# MVC razor refreshing view after timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, custom-attributes, redirecttoaction

I have come across an issue with my mvc razor website where it doesn't refresh properly my page after hitting a timeout.

Here's how I process the whole thing:

My application allows to go through multiple steps. Each step reloads the same view (index.cshtml), the difference being in the session variables. The session variables are used as parameters to make ajax calls to a webservice to get the content to be displayed within the page.

The user can select items displayed within the page and go to the next step. When they click next, it triggers a post (ajax to controller) that will add these items into a session variable so that the selection stays throughout the process and that the user can see all the items selected in the previous steps as he progresses.

I don't want the application to crash when accessing methods (like next, previous, save, etc.) because the session variables have expired.

The way I figured I would prevent that is by decorating my methods in the controller with an attribute that checks if a session variable (isActive) is set, and if it is not, I add a RedirectResult to my filterContext.

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

          if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipSessionExpireAttribute), false).Any()){
            return;
        }


        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["isActive"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["timedOut"] = "true";

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Session-Expired", true);

            return;
        }

    }  
}
```

I have set in my routes a route for this url so that it "triggers" the Index method of the controller. (which is the method that returns the view). That way, all session variables would reset, the URL is changed to "Session-Expired" and the page is reload (sending back to the first, default, step).

I tested and it does "trigger" the Index method and goes through it as intended and the Index method returns the view. The problem is, my page never gets reloaded.

Index method is:

```
    [SkipSessionExpire]
    [Themed]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      // Some code.

      return View();
    }
```

So I thought maybe it would be related to caching. I tried several methods found on this wonderful website such as adding:

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

with no real success.

I also tried some "hack" by redirecting to another action which would load a new page (test.cshtml) instead and this page would then redirect to the original view (index.cshtml). The test page worked when I tryed calling it with URL but for some reason, it still won't load the page when redirecting to the action.

My "Next" method (which doesn't get called because it is skipped because of the attribute, which is intended):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Themed]
    public JsonResult Next(object item)
    {
            //Some code.

            return Json((string)Session["CurrentUrl"]);

    }
```

The attribute [SessionExpire] is applied to the Controller (so every method within the controller gets it).

I just now tried to put a timeout on the ajax call made to the controller (from the view) in hopes that after tha ajax calls timeouts, it could just redirect to the Index page. It doesn't work (nothing happens on first click on the "next button", and second click bring me one step too far because it is like I went back to first page and then clicked next once).

Also, if I simply refresh the page after the timeout (manually). It realoads the first page with all session variables cleared (which is what I want to do programmatically).

To sum it, up. I would like to know if anyone has experienced something similar or if someone can guide me towards a solution so that I can get a way to refresh the page so that it's sent back to the first (default) step. Also, if I misunderstood something, feel free to tell me! I'm still learning so I'm more than glad to hear constructive feedbacks to help me understand how all of this works.

If you feel I'm too vague or you simply need additional details to help me solve this, just let me know and I'll add whatever is needed. I did quite a bit of research but I might have missed something so if you find something that could be useful, make sure to share.

Thanks!

Comment: - Temporary fix - 

I know it might not be optimal but I decided for now to simply catch ajax errors that occur because the ajax call never gets a response and to redirect using window.location.href

If anyone find something better than this, let me know :)